# Eclipse Bundle java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/console/IConsolePageParticipant

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have written my own implementation of `IConsolePageParticipant`.
But I get the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsolePageParticipant cannot be found by MyEditor_1.0.0
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:516)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:171)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 49 more
```

I also added the required bundle to Manifest.MF

```
  org.eclipse.ui.console
```

This is my extension point

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePageParticipants">
<consolePageParticipant class="com.todo.ConsolePageParticipant" id="com.todo.ConsolePageParticipant">
    <enablement>
        <instanceof value="org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole" />
    </enablement>
</consolePageParticipant>
```

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyEditor
Bundle-SymbolicName: MyEditor;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.todo.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.16.300",
 org.eclipse.jdt.ui;bundle-version="3.21.100",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.17.100",
 org.eclipse.core.filesystem;bundle-version="1.7.700",
 org.slf4j.api;bundle-version="1.7.30",
 org.eclipse.text,
  org.eclipse.ui.console,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor,
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.22.0",
 org.eclipse.debug.core;bundle-version="3.15.100",
 org.eclipse.jdt.launching;bundle-version="3.17.100",
 org.eclipse.debug.ui;bundle-version="3.14.500",
 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui;bundle-version="3.11.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Automatic-Module-Name: MyEditor
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
Bundle-Vendor:
```

So what I am missing?

Comment: Show us the MANIFEST.MF

Comment: And make sure your Launch Configuration is set to clear the Configuration space so that your plugin.xml changes are picked up.

Comment: When I start within eclipse it works fine, but when I export it as plugin and restart my eclipse than it not works. After I restart eclipse with clean it works fine, but I do not like it to restart with clean. Is their any other possibility?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by _"when I export it as plugin and restart my eclipse"_? How did you install your exported plugin into Eclipse? Did you put it in the `dropins` folder or what way did you choose to do this?

Comment: Yes I Export it and put into the dropin folder

Comment: All the more reason to show us the full MANIFEST.MF, more things are checked when you install a plugin than when you just test from within Eclipse. Also look in the .log file in the .metadata directory for any additional messages.

Comment: just updated now.